# Relative xpath not working when used with 'dot' inside the loop

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm pretty new to Python and Scrapy. So I created a spider and I'm having issues with relative paths. If I don't use the 'dot' inside the loop it prints the same result as long as the loop runs but if I use the 'dot' inside the loop it shows that it has scraped but the text it blank.

```
import scrapy
from demo_proj.items import JokeItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy import Selector


class JokesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jokes'
    allowed_domains=['kitco.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.kitco.com/'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        for joke in response.xpath("//div[@class='top15']"):
            l=ItemLoader(item=JokeItem(),selector=joke)
            l.add_xpath('news',".//div[@class='top15']/a/h3")
            l.add_xpath('time',".//div[@class='top15']/span[@class='post-date']")
            l.add_xpath('source',".//div[@class='top15']/span[@class='source']")
            yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: you must define `response=response` when defining itemloader

Comment: Thankyou for answering. I tried response= response initially but it gave the same result.

Comment: According to what I know so far the loop should work and give me all of the responses since  checked the response on scrapy  sheell too . But it just scrapes the same thing over and over again

Comment: with relative xpath should remove '/div[@class='top15']' from the item xpath, as this xpath is relative to it.

Comment: only scrapes one  item if I do that.

Answer (score 1):

`//div[@class='top15']` predicate is extra in your for loop. You narrowed it down to it before you get into for loop. The spider would be:

```py
class JokesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jokes'
    allowed_domains=['kitco.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.kitco.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for joke in response.xpath("//div[@class='top15']"):
            l = ItemLoader(item=JokeItem(), selector=joke)
            l.add_xpath('news', "./a/h3/text()")
            l.add_xpath('time', "./span[@class='post-date']/text()")
            l.add_xpath('source', "./span[@class='source']/text()")
            yield l.load_item()
```

The `items.py` would be:

```py
class JokeItem(scrapy.Item):
    news = scrapy.Field()
    time = scrapy.Field()
    source = scrapy.Field()
```

And this is few lines of my log:

```
{'news': ['The real gold price rally hasn’t even started yet, says analyst who '
          '...'],
 'source': ['Kitco Video News'],
 'time': ['Dec  9']}
2019-12-10 10:08:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.kitco.com/>
{'news': ['Who will win the 2020 presidential election? Doug Casey weighs in '
          'on ...'],
 'source': ['Kitco News'],
 'time': ['Dec  9']}
2019-12-10 10:08:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.kitco.com/>
{'news': ['What kind of a gold investor are you?'],
 'source': ['Kitco News'],
 'time': ['Dec  9']}
```

Comment: Now if I do this it scrapes empty items

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, I put the whole spider class and `items.py` and it works fine for me.

Comment: I did exactly as you said but it just gives me one output.I will keep looking though Thank you for your help

Comment: Add your log in the question maybe it shows something.@RamshaIlyas